# ExtJS Specify the existing date format for conversion

Tags: json, extjs, date-conversion

I have a lot of data being displayed with ExtJS, and I can't figure out how to specify what the format of the data is so that it will be converted correctly. We are trying to display the data in m/d/y format. The data is being output in Ymd format (20130214, no hyphens). How can I tell ExtJS what format the date is in so that it can be parsed?

The dates are retrieved from a remote service via JSON, so all I can change is the column header JSON file.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I have tried setting submitFormat and dateFormat parameters on the column but they have not worked.

Answer (score 0):

In your model, specify the field like so:

```
...
fields: [
  ...
  {name: 'theDate', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'Ymd'},
  ...
],
...
```

Note that the data as retrieved by: `myRecord.get('theDate');` is a JavaScript `Date` object, so you can then format it lots of ways, such as:

```
Ext.Date.format(myRecord.get('theDate'), "m/d/Y");
```